# R populate multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, r, multidimensional-array, rstudio

Hi I am stuck with one of these simple but time-consuming errors:

How can I populate an array with loops? I know I am on a C approach here
and R isn't C.

```
  Data <-[SOMETHING HERE]
  One <-200
  Two <-100
  array222 <- array(0,length(SomeLength))


  for (i in 1:One)
  {
    for (j in 1:Two)
    {
      array222[i][j] = sample(Data,1)   
    }
```

I want to populate the array with random samples from another dataset but all 
I get is this:

```
Warning in array222[i][j] = sample(Data, 1) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you wouldn't use loops to do this in R. You'd just do

```
array222 <- matrix(sample(Data, One*Two, replace=T), nrow=One, ncol=Two)
```

But going back to your code, you fail to properly initialize your `array222` variable. The `matrix()` syntax is probably easier for a 2-D array, but you could also use `array(0, dim=c(One,Two))`. You need to create it with the proper dimensions.

And additionally, the proper way to index a dimensional array is

```
array222[i,j]  #NOT array222[i][j]
```